# Flask - Server is up but returns 404

Tags: python, flask

When I try to run my app with a route for "/", it shows that the server is running, but when I go to it I get a 404. I'm following [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world).

[image: directory structure]

`microblog.py`:

```
from app import app
```

`app/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import routes
```

`app/routes.py`

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

In the microblog directory I execute:

```
set FLASK_APP=microblog.py
flask run
 * Serving Flask app "microblog.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Navigating to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` outputs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jan/2020 14:43:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: You don't need to decorate any functions with the route twice

Comment: @C.Nivs Ok, so I seperated each route for a seperate implemantetion and it really solved the 404! It gave me other errors but solved the 404. Thanks!

Comment: That's perfectly valid if you want 2 routes to do the same thing.

Comment: @dushkin How is `app` getting into `routes.py`? What other errors did you get?

Comment: @C.Nivs doesn't matter using 2 route path, this just show two end point url for same function

Comment: If you do `set FLASK_ENV=development` and then run it again, what happens?

Comment: @blueteeth After leaving only the '/' route I got: NameError: name 'app' is not defined

Comment: So you need to import `app` in `routes.py`.

Comment: changed routes.py to from app import app

@app.route('/')
def index1():
    return 'Hello, World!'

Answer (score 0):

this code is working fine, you forgot to add `app` in the routes.py

just add `from app import app` in `routes.py` and run the app according to tutorial, it will work

Comment: I changed routes.py to:
from app import app @app.route('/') def index1(): return 'Hello, World!' 
But received again NameError: name 'app' is not defined together with lines like 
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jan/2020 16:31:00] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jan/2020 16:31:00] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
etc.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "C:\Users\username\PythonProjects\microblog\microblog.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app     
  File "C:\Users\username\PythonProjects\microblog\app\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from app import routes    
  File "C:\Users\username\PythonProjects\microblog\app\routes.py", line 1, in <module>
    @app.route('/')

Comment: this `"C:\Users\username\PythonProjects\microblog\app_init_.py` should be `"C:\Users\username\PythonProjects\microblog\app\__init__.py` you need to create `__init__.py` file inside app folder

Comment: Thank you. I will verify it tomorrow morning at office :)

Comment: I am sorry - the log was not accurate. When I save the comment, the app\\__init__ turned to be app_init_ ... because I didn't use double backslashes . It is actually app\\_\_init_\_.py

Comment: Also, I made a change to some py files, but it doesn't seem that sever is being updated. Even when intentionally I insert a source code error, when I execute "flask run" the server runs as before. What am I missing?

Comment: well you can start from the sctrach again, i also followed the same procedure got my server running, btw what error you are getting now?

Comment: I changed app = Flask(__name__) to app1 = Flask(__name__) just to see that something changed in server. But when I "flask run", the server is up and when I am reaching http://127.0.0.1:5000/ I still get 
 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
File "...\microblog\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py",line 39,in reraise
raise value
File "...\microblog\microblog.py",line 1,in <module>
from app import app
File "...\microblog\app\\_\_init_\_.py",line 13,in <module>
from app import routes
File "...\microblog\app\routes.py",line 1,in <module>
@app.route('/')
NameError: name 'app' is not defined

Comment: "start from the sctrach again" - do you mean creating the venv again?

Comment: shouldn't `app = Flask(name)` be `app = Flask(__name__)` ? you can use same venv just del rest files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206779/discussion-between-dushkin-and-sahasrara62).